# How to Pass NFT Trait Property Securely To Smart Contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc721

I have an NFT staking contract that issues rewards based on the property rarity of the NFT staked. The four property tiers are 1,2,3 and 4.

When a user clicks stakeNFT(tokenId, nftTier), I use the tokenId to pull the metadata json property from IPFS and send the NFT tier to the smart contract.

The issue here is while this works on the user interface of our website, anyone can use Etherscan directly and input an tier that isn’t in their NFT so as to earn more rewards.

How do I verify the NFT tier based on the tokenId onchain?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is an ideal solution to making this work.  My first suggestion would be to have the user sign a message that encodes the actual tier from the frontend, but you're contract would also need to know this value as well for that to work.  Without having a mapping of each NFT and their tier in your minting contract, there isn't a good way to ensure the user can't put in anything they like.

Comment: What solution did you use? I'm in similar situation.

Comment: I ended up using a merkel tree on a backend to verify the tokenId, let me know if you want more details